# MySQL - Database with multiple schemas where table and column names are different

Tags: php, mysql, schema

Is there a way to have one database that can be represented with different table and column names?

I'm creating a large refactoring of an API, where it only makes sense to rename quite some table and column names in the MySQL database, but the old version of the API still needs to read and write to the existing database. The data is largely the same and the versions can easily co-exist. There is no chance to have two databases running in parallel.

The new API domain layer is fully separated from the persistance layer, but in the persistance layer, I would like to create it properly using new table and column names, instead of having to convert the names for each query.

Is there a way to represent the database structure in multiple ways - effectively making the naming variable? Can you suggest me a solution? 
Is there e.g. a way to solve this by replacing a database schema?

I would like the two versions of the API to read and write to database where tables can exist with this (below) difference in naming - but the table and data is the same.

```
+----------------------------+  +-------------------------+
|          old_items         |  |        new_items        |
+----+----------+------------+  +----+----------+---------+
| id | meta_key | meta_value |  | id | item_key | item_id |
+----+----------+------------+  +----+----------+---------+
```

The application is written in PHP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to rename the column, when you can use alias when getting the column name. like

```
select metavalue as itemvalue from tablename
```

Or

Alternatively you can create two seperate tables for each your entity. That makes sense.

Comment: I am using aliases for every column already, but I currently have to base it on the old table and column names and therefore I will have to make the rewrite twice. Once now and once again when I deprecate the old API - instead of just writing the new names right away. My current solution is that I created a lot of helper functions to convert old naming to new naming and set this whole schema up in an associative array. It's not exactly good for performance and it takes too much time to create.

Comment: If setting up two different tables, then I would need some kind of service queue to move entries from one to the other. Is that what you are suggesting, or do I misunderstand? This kind of queue would not be a viable solution.

Comment: Thats your code you know how to manage it. Just a suggestion, dont make lot of helper functions or changes, just put it as v1 and create a new v2 api version.

Comment: How do you then suggest to manage it in my code if there are two different table versions??